# Moving Redis Hash Fields Efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am trying to remove and move multiple values from one Redis hash to another Redis hash in Node.js.

Basically I have two hashes set up: Current and History.

When I receive information that contains a 1 I store some string data into the Current hash.
I continually do this until I receive info that contains a 0 or 2.

Then I want to remove all values from the Current hash that match this new message's string and put those into the History hash.

I am in the process of writing a function that just reads all the values from the Current Hash, compares their strings to the new info string, and then removes and adds when there is a match. But I already can see how this would be really inefficient if there was a lot of items in the Current Hash.

Is there a better way to remove multiple matching values in a hash and easily move them to a different hash?

Comment: Would there be a problem just adding to both hashes to begin with and expiring from current only?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I need to keep values separate until a 0 or 2 is received. Yes that would work but they need to be separate. I am working with SNMP traps that when received, tell you if the trap is still in progress or has been resolved. This is why they need to be kept apart. I have it working with just reading all values from current and checking with the input value. Then writing to history and deleting, but this operation would be expensive and timely if the hash was huge would it not?